# Ler uma lista de listas em txt python 3

Tags: python, fopen

Eu tenho uma lista de listas bem gigante e ela fica atrapalhando o meu código.

Então eu queria salvar essa lista em um arquivo txt e pedir pro algoritmo salvar essa lista em uma nova variável.

Vamos supor que a minha lista de listas seja:

```
   [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]]
```

Se eu uso:

```
    text_file = open("lista", "r")
    lista = text_file.read().split(',')
```

Então a minha variável "lista" devolve, por exemplo:

```
    lista[0] = "[[[1]"
```

E na verdade eu queria que ele compreendesse que lista[0] =

```
    [[1],[2]]
```

Como eu faço pra abrir um arquivo e o python entender as estruturas internas do texto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta você *serializar* seu objeto antes de salvá-lo em arquivo. No Python, há a biblioteca nativa [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html) que você pode utilizar:

**Salvando o objeto em arquivo**

Para salvar o objeto em arquivo, basta você utilizar a função `dump`. Basta você indicar o objeto que deseja salvar e a *stream* que representa o arquivo:

```
import pickle

lista = [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]]

with open("data.txt", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(lista, file)
```

Desta forma o objeto `lista` será salvado no arquivo `data.txt`. Perceba que o arquivo deve ser aberto para escrita binária (`wb`). O conteúdo do arquivo para este exemplo será:

```
\x80\x03]q\x00(]q\x01(]q\x02K\x01a]q\x03K\x02ae]q\x04(]q\x05K\x03a]q\x06K\x04aee.
```

Que nada mais é que a representação do objeto.

**Recuperando os dados do arquivo**

Para recuperar o objeto do arquivo, basta utilizar a função `load`. Basta apenas indicar a *stream* do arquivo que deseja obter os dados como parâmetro:

```
with open("data.txt", "rb") as file:
    lista2 = pickle.load(file)
```

Assim, `lista2` será uma lista de listas, assim como `lista` inicialmente. Podemos verificar acessando a posição 0 da mesma:

```
print(lista2[0]) # -> [[1], [2]]
```

Ou até verificar se `lista2` é igual à `lista`:

```
print(lista == lista2) # -> True
```

Comment: Respondi sugerindo o uso do `eval()` mas não sabia a dimensão do  [problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice), muito boa resposta! +1

Comment: @MathiasFalci é, difícil dizer com exatidão, mas sempre há uma maneira preferível à `eval`. Neste caso em específico talvez nem seria tão crítico, mas seria bom evitar. Fora o fato que a biblioteca `pickle` suporta tipos mais complexos do que apenas uma lista.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente ignorar o primeiro e ultimo colchetes com :

```
 text_file = open("lista", "r")
 lista = text_file.read()[1:-2].split(',')
```